# Ubuntu 19.10 login loop - no common solution to this problem seems to help

Tags: login, 19.10

A few days ago I started to experience a login loop on my Lenovo Legion Y540 with Ubuntu 19.10 installed. This is not the first time I've run into this issue, so I tried a few common solutions, but they do not seem to help.
I've tried switching to lightdm, deleted all of my gnome extensions, checked /tmp permissions, removed my graphic drivers and a bunch of other stuff, but nothing seems to be breaking the loop.
I'm new to Linux, so I might be missing something very obvious.
People seem to be asking for the output of the following command, cause it might help

```
egrep 'WW|EE' /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

so here's mine:

```
[   13.127] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   13.127] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   13.127] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   13.127] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   13.127] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   13.138] (WW) Falling back to the old probe method for fbdev
```

I have also notices a file called Xorg.1.log, which also might help and the previous command for that file gives me:

```
[   18.407] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   18.407] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   18.407] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   18.407] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   18.407] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   18.657] (WW) Falling back to the old probe method for modesetting
[   18.657] (WW) Falling back to the old probe method for fbdev
[   18.679] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
[   18.876] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Option "Primary GPU" is not used
```

I might have broken something while trying out different solutions, but this is the current state. If I need to provide any more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check if the problem with a user by creating new user:

  ```
  sudo adduser newuser && usermod -aG sudo newuser
  ```

  If you could login with a newuser without loop, then the problem with a user configuration files and you could do the next:
- `sudo mkdir /home/newuser/backup && sudo mv /home/olduser/* /home/newuser/backup/`
- `sudo cp -fr /etc/skel/* /home/olduser/ && chown -R olduser:olduser /home/olduser`

Comment: I am able to login as the newly created user. I'm not sure what the second and third command are supposed to do, but they still don't let me login as olduser. Is there at least an easy way to move my configurations from olduser to newuser and continue using newuser?

Comment: Updated the answer. Second command will backup your olduser files. Third command will copy default configuration files to your olduser home folder and will change ownership to your olderuser. Just replace olduser with your actual old username.

Comment: Well I was thinking to spare me the time of logging into everything again, setting up my toolbar, startup programs etc. If any of those is even possible.

Comment: If you don't know what broken then it is easier to reconfigure it again, then copying config files and directories one by one and re login again and again to check if you've copied healthy or bad config file. Some applications such as Intellij Idea, PyCharm or other big applications could create directories you could move back then, but check ownership.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue a few months ago, i followed those steps to solve the issue :

> First can you login via console (Ctlr+Alt+F1, F2 or F3) ?

If you can, try to backup your `/home/$user/.config` directory. To do that just move it to another location/name with `mv`:

```
mv ~/.config ~/dotconfig_backup
```

Then reboot and retry to login via your graphical interface.

If it doesn't fix your issue, you can also try to move the following folders:

- `~/.cache`
- `~/.gconf`
- `~/.gnupg`
- `~/.gnome2`

The source of the issue for me was an installed gnome extension

Let me now if it helped you :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to help :(
I've backed up all of the folders you mentioned (except for ~/.gconf because it doesn't seem to exist on my computer), but I'm still in the loop after rebooting...

Comment: Ok, so the next step is to try to login via another graphical interface and if you success, you'll have to investigate what changes you recently made (during last time you successfully logged in your GUI)

Comment: Did you installed Gnome Extension during your last successful GUI session ?

Comment: My default is gdm3 and logging in doesn't work with gdm3 nor lightdm. I am almost certain I did not install any gnome extensions during my last successful GUI login, but I might have updated something via Software Center (I don't recall if it was a gnome extension or not)

Comment: ok, you are not able to even load to lightgdm ?

Comment: I am able to load the login screen, but not my desktop after entering my password

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105127/discussion-between-appygg-and-vuk-bibic).